# Using a non-null conditional LAG() function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried applying a couple solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but my question seems to be somewhat different from the OP's from this post.

---

I have a large dataset `data` in MySQL:

```
id          date          val
aaaaa       2021-01-01    TRUE
aaaaa       2021-01-02    FALSE
aaaaa       2021-01-03    FALSE
aaaaa       2021-01-04    TRUE
aaaaa       2021-01-05    FALSE
aaaaa       2021-01-06    TRUE
aaaaa       2021-01-07    FALSE
...
aaaaa       2021-12-31    FALSE
aaaab       2021-01-01    TRUE
aaaab       2021-01-02    FALSE
...
zzzzz       2021-12-31    FALSE
```

Here, `id` is a string-type data, `date` ranges from `2021-01-01` to `2021-12-31` without any missing days, and `val` contains a boolean value, `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `data` is ordered by `id, date`.

I would like to add two columns, `lagged_date` and `date_diff`.

- `lagged_date` contains the previous date of the `id` where `val = TRUE`.
- `date_diff` calculates the difference of the number of days between `date` and `lagged_date` in that row.

Ideally, my final dataset should look like this:

```
id          date          val        lagged_date     date_diff
aaaaa       2021-01-01    TRUE       NULL            NULL
aaaaa       2021-01-02    FALSE      2021-01-01      1
aaaaa       2021-01-03    FALSE      2021-01-01      2
aaaaa       2021-01-04    TRUE       2021-01-01      3
aaaaa       2021-01-05    FALSE      2021-01-04      1
aaaaa       2021-01-06    TRUE       2021-01-04      2
aaaaa       2021-01-07    FALSE      2021-01-06      1
...
aaaaa       2021-12-31    FALSE      2021-12-25      6
aaaab       2021-01-01    TRUE       NULL            NULL
aaaab       2021-01-02    FALSE      2021-01-01      1
...
```

(Note that this data is also ordered by `id, date`)

I tried a following query:

```
SELECT *,
       MAX(val) OVER (
          PARTITION BY id, val
          ORDER BY date
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
       ) AS lagged_date,
       DATE_DIFF(date, lagged_date, DAY) AS date_diff
  FROM data
```

but the `lagged_date` does not produce my desired output, only produces the lagged `val`. I tried `MAX(date)` also, but to no avail.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Get your previous date using a correlated subquery and then an outer query to calculated the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery to find the previous date for each 'id' where is 'TRUE' then use DATE_DIFF function.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.val,
  (SELECT t2.date FROM data t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.val = TRUE AND t2.date < t1.date ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) as lagged_date,
  DATEDIFF(t1.date, (SELECT t2.date FROM data t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.val = TRUE AND t2.date < t1.date ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1)) as date_diff
FROM data t1
```